# I want the first letter from column a, and append to column b

Tags: powershell

I've seen lots of posts about combining columns and various things close but I just can't figure out this.

I have a csv with 2 columns, First and Last. I want to take the first letter in First and add it to the beginning to Last. I know how to append and do everything else but I don't know how to take just the first letter of First.

Example of what I'm trying to get:

First           Last

John            Doe            JDoe

I've tried this but it results in null-values expression error.

```
 $Names = Import-Csv -Path .\Names.csv
Foreach ($Name in $Names){
$Fullname = $Name.First.substring(0,1) + $name.last 

"Fullname is $Fullname"
}
```

Raw Content:

```
First ,Last,Username
John,Doe,
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? :) Given that the only expression on which you're calling a method is `$Name.First`, my best guess is that the CSV doesn't have the correct headers or format (different delimiter than comma perhaps?).

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $Fullname = $Name.First.substring(0,1) + $Name.Last
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: As expected, that means the expression `$Name.First` resolves to $null. Can you paste the raw CSV data [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69466979/edit)?

Comment: So it's not a CSV? I see no commas :)

Comment: If that' the raw data, use `Import-Csv -Path .\Names.csv -Delimiter " "`, so that PowerShell knows not to split on comma, but on space.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to post raw data as you asked. I was just trying to mimic what it looks like, apologies

Comment: `Get-Content -Path .\Names.csv -Raw |Set-Clipboard`, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69466979/edit), scroll down to the bottom of the text box and paste the data in your clipboard (ie. `[Ctrl]+V`)

Comment: Added to bottom of my question, thank you

Comment: Looks like the trailing space after `First` in the header of the CSV is the problem, `Import-Csv` interprets it as part of the column name. `$Name.'First '.Substring(0,1)` will work, but you'll probably want to sanitize the CSV instead

Comment: I can't believed I missed that, that did it, thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237894/discussion-between-philip-hudson-and-mathias-r-jessen).